# How can I extract pure dopamine from the body?

Tags: biology, science-in-society

Through scientific shennaganins, it has been discovered that humans are the best source of producing dopamine. By injecting them with a certain manufactory substance, the body creates a high return of the chemical dopamine in the brain, up to 100 times the normal amount. This undoubtedly kills the victim within minutes. The chemical dosage can't be lessened and will always lead to death, making it a bad investment for a money making product. However, the dopamine released in the brain can be extracted and synthesized, making it perfect for a street drug. An illegal operation is now operating out of Europe producing this drug from stolen dopamine. People are abducted or subdued to offer no resistance, then given this chemical, leading to thousands of deaths or disappearences.

What is the best way to extract pure, uncontaminated dopamine from the body ?

Comment: Have you checked that dopamine will cross the blood-brain barrier? If not it's not a candidate for any known drug delivery system. Also if you want a big enough dopamine release to try that extraction method heroin is not the drug of choice.

Comment: "A needle is injected into the brain, extracting the chemical in order for it to be turned into the street drug." - this procedure? You can't. You can find higher concentration of dopamine in banana. If you can process brains to extract it, you are better off with buying bananas than abducting humans, buying heroin etc.

Comment: @Mołot: Now I'm imagining a drug cartel with massive illegal banana plantations. Everyone fears The Banana Republic.

Comment: @Giter minor genetic tweak to get dopamine levels x10 or x100 up and you're golden!

Comment: @Mołot http://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2013-02-28

Comment: *"Through scientific shennaganins, it has been discovered that humans are the best source of producing dopamine"* this is the same kind of "scientific" shenanigan that says vaccines are evil and the Earth is flat.

Answer (score 9):

Using heroin the way you depict is going to make the drug too expensive.

Take some bacteria or other suitable microorganism, genetically engineer them to produce dopamine, grow them into an incubator and purify the dopamine.

It will cost less than giving heroin to random strangers, will give you less problems of finding and disposing of those strangers and will be a more reliable method.

Comment: Two minor notes: 1) bananas already produce dopamine, so you don't need engineer anything, just set up banana jam factory with dopamine as a nice under-the-counter business and 2) As far as I know, yeast are easier to use for production of arbitrary pharmaceutical substances (ie https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3728191/ )

Comment: I love when an evil overlord plan is fooled by the wonderful joined powers of ECONOMICS and LOGISTICS!

Answer (score 6):

Extracting it from the brain is incredibly inefficient(compared to other organelles), then again its not like its hard to get in the first place from far less controversial methods.

Anyways, as far as this 'procedure' goes, you wouldn't be able to extract dopamine from the brain with a needle very well. You might be able to drain the blood from the brain and extract it from that or you could just take the whole brain and throw it in a blender and work from there.

Regardless, whatever liquid you extract will be impure no matter what you do and will require processing to refine out the dopamine.